# Spring Integration's `ImapIdleAdapter` doesn't mark messages as read

Tags: email, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have declared a mail listener with Spring Integration like this:

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Mail.imapIdleAdapter(getUrl())
                    .searchTermStrategy((s, f) -> new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false))
                    .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true)
                    .shouldDeleteMessages(false)
                    .get())
            .<Message>handle((payload, header) -> handle(payload)).get();
}
```

In my test mail account I have a few 'unread' and a few 'read' messages. Starting the application I see in the logs that the listener fetches all of the 'unread' messages over and over again without ever marking them as 'read'.

Given that I specified `shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true)` I would expect the Adapter to mark a message as read after fetching it.

Am I understanding and/or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Artem Bilan's hint on activating debug output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73111497/1225882) I found out that the mailbox was opened in read-only mode.

And thanks to [Gary Russell's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59613959/1225882) I tried removing the `.get()` call on the `ImapIdleChannelAdapterSpec`:

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Mail.imapIdleAdapter(getUrl())
                    .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true)
                    .shouldDeleteMessages(false))
            .<Message>handle((payload, header) -> handle(payload)).get();
}
```

Now the mailbox gets opened in read-write mode and marking the messages with the `SEEN` flag works fine.

I also don't actually need the custom `SearchTermStrategy` now as Artem Bilan already suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In this type of situations we recommend to set:

```
.javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "true"))
```

on that `Mail.imapIdleAdapter()`.

Probably your e-mail server really does not support that `\seen` flag, so the message is marked as `read` via some other flag.

So, with that mail debugging option you should see some interesting info in your logs.

The logic in our default `DefaultSearchTermStrategy` is like this around that `Flags.Flag.SEEN` :

```
if (supportedFlags.contains(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
                NotTerm notSeen = new NotTerm(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true));
                if (searchTerm == null) {
                    searchTerm = notSeen;
                }
                else {
                    searchTerm = new AndTerm(searchTerm, notSeen);
                }
            }
```

See if you really need a custom strategy and why a default one is not enough for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#search-term

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, it helped me a lot! The server does suppoert the `SEEN` flag, but the mailbox was opened in read-only mode. I elaborated on it in a separate answer.